# Parser Error when retrieving form posted data in C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, forms

Trying to retrieve posted data from HTML form into C# page.

However I am receiving this error:

> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: 'Ass2.CarPage' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CarPage.aspx.cs"  Inherits="Ass2.CarPage"%>
>
> Line 2:
>
> Line 3:

HTML Code:

```
<!--Car Search Form-->
        <div id="Search_Form">
            <form name="Car Search" action="CarPage.aspx" method="post">
                <h1 align="center">Search For A Car Now: </h1>
                <h2 align="center">
                    <select name="Car">
                        <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
                        <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
                        <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                        <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
                        <option value="Vauxhall">Vauxhall</option>
                    </select>
                    <h1 align="center">
                        <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
                    </h1>
            </form>
        </div>
```

C# Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CarPage.aspx.cs"  Inherits="Ass2.CarPage"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<%     
if (Request.Form["Car"] == "Volvo") 
{
    Response.Redirect("VolvoHomepage.html");
}

if (Request.Form["Car"] == "Ford") 
{
    Response.Redirect("FordHomepage.html");
}
if (Request.Form["Car"] == "Mercedes") 
{
    Response.Redirect("MercedesHomepage.html");
}
if (Request.Form["Car"] == "Audi") 
{
    Response.Redirect("AudiHomepage.html");
}
if (Request.Form["Car"] == "Vauxhall") 
{
Response.Redirect("VauxhallHomepage.html");
}
%>  

</body>
</html>
```

ASPX.CS Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start with not writing `C#` and `VB` code on the same page. Remove the `End If`.

Comment: @VDWWD - tried this but it still doesnt stop the error mesasge

Comment: You haven't shown us the code behind page.

Comment: @JamieObrien What do you mean "empty"? Is there absolutely no text at all in your .aspx.cs page?

Comment: @mason when I say empty I mean I havent added anything too it

Comment: I don't care if you haven't added anything to it. It's still an essential part of your question. Put the code in your question.

Comment: Do you have a `Ass2.CarPage` class defined anywhere?  Wherever it is, it's not inheriting from `System.Web.UI.Page`, hence the issue.

Comment: Added it @mason

Comment: Change the namespace of your code behind from `WebApplication` to `Ass2` and the class name from `WebForm1` to `CarPage`. Does that resolve issue?

Comment: @mason yes this has resolved the issue, thankyou very much, sorry for being slow im still learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that you have a class `Ass2.CarPage` that is not inheriting from `System.Web.UI.Page`. The class that it found was likely the class in the designer file, which is only a partial class definition and so doesn't have the inheritance declared there.

The actual code behind file had the wrong namespace and class, so it wasn't picked up. By changing it from `WebApplication2.WebForm` to `Ass2.CarPage` the partial classes now are referring to the same time and thus get "merged", and since your code behind inherits from the correct class, it all works.

On a side note, you should take the inline C# code out of of your ASPX page and put it in the `Page_Load` method of your code behind. It's silly to mix C# into the ASPX page when that's what the code behind is intended for.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.Form["Car"] == "Volvo") 
            {
                Response.Redirect("VolvoHomepage.html");
            }

            else if (Request.Form["Car"] == "Ford") 
            {
                Response.Redirect("FordHomepage.html");
            }
            else if (Request.Form["Car"] == "Mercedes") 
            {
                Response.Redirect("MercedesHomepage.html");
            }
            else if (Request.Form["Car"] == "Audi") 
            {
                Response.Redirect("AudiHomepage.html");
            }
            else if (Request.Form["Car"] == "Vauxhall") 
            {
                Response.Redirect("VauxhallHomepage.html");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you should probably make sure the form values exist before accessing them. But I'll leave that as an exercise for you.